# How to automatically infer generic type of variable

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
let array: Array<string> = ["hello", "hi"];
// What I want: 
// let array: Array<?> = ["hello", "hi"];
// Type should be inferred as Array<string> automatically
```

Impossible on a variable, however totally possible with a function.

```
function arrayFunc<T>(array: Array<T>): Array<T> {
  return array;
};
let dataFromFunc = arrayFunc(["hello"]);
// T is inferred as string automatically
```

Now, this seems a bit a weird why I want this, since I can just do `let array = [1, 2]`, and have the whole thing be inferred for me as `number[]`. However, once the type gets more complicated like an object, I would like to keep the type checking and autocomplete.

```
type Options<T extends string> = {
  a: number,
  b: number,
  c: T
}[];
```

And now to declare the variable:

```
// Ideally: let options: Options<?> = [...]
// Note: NOT let options: Options<any>, I want the exact type inferred, just like a function.
let options: Options<"a" | "b" | "c" | "d"> = [
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: "a"
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: "b"
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: "c"
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: "d"
  },
];
```

Putting the generic in myself has it's purpose at times, but I want to just keep adding options in this case and have the generic type inferred automatically. Again, this is possible with a function:

```
function optionsFunc<T extends string>(options: Options<T>): Options<T> {
  return options;
}

let optionsFromFunc = optionsFunc([...]);
// T is automatically inferred as <"a" | "b" | "c" | "d">
```

However, this seems very weird since now I am passing everything into a runtime function that just returns itself.

You may be wondering why not just create the array directly on the function that uses it? Well, I want to store my options in a separate file and reuse it in multiple parts of my program.

Is there any good way to do this or solve my use case?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAhgTjUE8BcECCdEB4DOYYEsA7AcwD4IBeCAbQCIALEYYAe1oBoIH9aBdAbgBQAemEQA6vSiQAkhADuUQmBShIseMjQYEmAPzkqdRszadufIaIgAVBAAcQEbPRYBXYABMIAIydEAMxA4EG8obG1NHDwiMmg3MBYAW2l8AGMoZgRBQQC3QjSwfBZCaB0AMXy0zBtSAAoNRBR0KNqASmadGvIAb0EICBhwNxhSxoQhAF8hNQhPaShymGTKgsoyzVW0uuMmVj42qzEbCHwIwOChsIjcAhJ4xJSijKycsAcnAHl7IpLsGogIAAHmAQIRPDcYiRDBA%20gMoChCG4kn4YOx%20r5EcjUeiBmkUDZBJNqLwctYZJ4QJlgFpZiwfsVCNgUN9fkz9DDqAA6HmkukMv4sgXs2hQWgQAA%20XB84qltDSsq4nlonIxcIG0BQAEZcRqfCgAEy6vEoUW0DGTXXq%20Ha42YiBGjEm6XmgaWtVOzUQHWe-UOu34rgKi1Wz0I712v2OjUQQO0ZUhwSk3JVNkQels7BbAHA0HgyF3Mh1DOM5kQVml7odcvC-61WEYoZgEalEt-KZk44PZKpF4006EIIha4QTBmyUuifyxXxlWCfmZpYrKrrNtMrY7D0x8M%20mNRgOmsWJgbWr27vWGg8u48N7e232Xz1x4Nu0N3iMP-1P00J19JtpAA)

Comment: Currently there is nothing better than a helper function; see the answer to the linked question for more information.